# Access keys not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility

Problem is that the focus does'nt seem to shift to the footer links when access key 0 is pressed in chrome.Works okay for IE and firefox.Here's what am doing,

```
<ul class="hidden">
   <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:this.href='#Footer';" accesskey="0">Footer</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="FooterDiv">
<a id="Footer" name="Footer" href="javascript:;" class="hidden">Footer</a>
//More footer links here.

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Chrome available right now, but try <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+Key. Think they implemented it like Firefox did.

Comment: (alt + key) is the combination for chrome.The problem is that the focus doesn't transfer to the FooterDiv when i press (alt + 0).Works okay for IE and firefox but not chrome.